# WP_Query is printing out only one post when posts_per_page is set to multiple

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, wp-query, shortcode

I made my own custom post type and the shortcode to output the custom post type. It all works fine so far, but once I tried adding more posts I still get only one on the page and not more. `posts_per_page` is set to 3 or more but still nothing.

```
// Custom Post Type for Use Cases page slider

function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'use_cases',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Use Cases' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Use_Case' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

// Shortcode for Use Cases caption

add_shortcode('Use_Case', 'use_case_shortcode_query');
function use_case_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
    echo "working";
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '3',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        )
   , $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '3',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases'
        ));
    //print_r($posts);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts()):
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
                    //echo var_dump($posts->the_post());
            $posts->the_post();
            $out = '<div class="use_case_boxes">
                <h4>Name: <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '">'.get_the_title() .'</a></h4>
                <p class="Film_desc">'.get_the_content().'</p>';
                // add here more...
            $out .='</div>';
    /* these arguments will be available from inside $content
        get_permalink()
        get_the_content()
        get_the_category_list(', ')
        get_the_title()
        and custom fields
        get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true);
    */
    endwhile;
  else:
    return; // no posts found
endif;
  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are re-initializing the out variable that is why it shows only one  product

```
// Custom Post Type for Use Cases page slider

function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'use_cases',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Use Cases' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Use_Case' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

// Shortcode for Use Cases caption

add_shortcode('Use_Case', 'use_case_shortcode_query');
function use_case_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
    echo "working";
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '3',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        )
   , $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '3',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases'
        ));
    //print_r($posts);
  $output = '';
$out = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts()):
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
                    //echo var_dump($posts->the_post());
            $posts->the_post();
            $out .= '<div class="use_case_boxes">
                <h4>Name: <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '">'.get_the_title() .'</a></h4>
                <p class="Film_desc">'.get_the_content().'</p>';
                // add here more...
            $out .='</div>';
    /* these arguments will be available from inside $content
        get_permalink()
        get_the_content()
        get_the_category_list(', ')
        get_the_title()
        and custom fields
        get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true);
    */
    endwhile;
  else:
    return; // no posts found
endif;
  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I don't see any changes in your code and it's still not working?

Comment: Ops, my bad it's working. Still don't get it with re-initializing

Comment: in your code `$out = '<div class="use_case_boxes">` i made it `$out .= '<div class="use_case_boxes">`  you are defining the variable again so the old values get replaced